# Use an executable in a powershel pipeline

Tags: powershell, scripting

Hi I use an executable to decode some log file, like this:

```
E:\DailyLogPrinter.bat -sourceFile E:\SScope.log -targetFile E:\Output.log
```

But I want to use the same .bat file in a pipeline in a powershell script, the first part get logs lines of the last 30 minutes, then I want to decode those lines:

```
$TTime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-30 )
(Get-Content "E:\SiteScope\logs\SiteScope$(get-date -f yyyy_MM_dd).v2.log").where({
    [datetime]($_ -replace "(^\S+\s\S+).*",'$1') -ge $TTime
},'SkipUntil') 

| use the output with DailyLogPrinter.bat | do some other thing with decoded data
```

UPDATE:

So I opened the bat file, and it seems that doesn't support pipeline input, these are the entrails of the bat file:

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT_PATH=%~dp0

%~d0
cd %SCRIPT_PATH%

set CLASS_PATH=%CLASS_PATH%;..\WEB-INF\lib\ss_platform.jar;..\WEB-INF\lib\log4j.jar;..\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec.jar;..\WEB-INF\lib\javacore.jar;

set JAVA_LOCATION=..\java\bin
if exist ..\..\..\java\bin\java.exe set JAVA_LOCATION=..\..\..\java\bin
if exist ..\..\..\..\java\bin\java.exe set JAVA_LOCATION=..\..\..\..\java\bin

set MAIN_CLASS=com.mercury.sitescope.platform.log.printer.DailyLogPrinter

%JAVA_LOCATION%\java.exe -Xmx512M -classpath %CLASS_PATH% %MAIN_CLASS% %*
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping the .bat in a `ForEach-Object`?  For example: `Do something | ForEach-Object {use the output of "Do something" with DailyLogPrinter.bat}  | do some other thing with decoded data`

Comment: Its a pretty vague question... *do something | do somethingelse*. Pipelines are used to pass values from return of one function to argument of another (if it accepts it). You will need to be specific in what you're asking

Comment: @Jawad I added more context

Comment: Does the program accept pipeline input?  Otherwise save the file and send its name to it.

Comment: Can you add detail on how you Invoke / Call / Use DailyLogPrinter.bat without it being in the pipeline

Comment: Hi @thomschumacher is in the question: E:\DailyLogPrinter.bat -sourceFile E:\SScope.log -targetFile E:\Output.log

Comment: @boxdog Im trying what you said, is taking a long time, I dont know if it is working, but if it work, that means that from every line of log will be executing the .bat? this will be more ineficient than outputing the file and run it a single time in all the log lines, I am correct?

Comment: How do you use -sourcefile and -targetfile?